# SQL Server convert bigint column to a datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'm really a noob with msql and I need help for this:

I have a table with only 3 columns:

```
devicename, status, timeticks
```

`timeticks` is a 18 digit `bigint` value (for example *635924050579957219*) and I need to produce a report where `timeticks` is displayed as a datetime value.

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The example value u have posted is too large. Even if u r using milliseconds as unit, it will take u to the dinosaurs age.

Comment: Could you please tell us to which date the value 635924050579957219 should convert and how you calculated that date?

Comment: well, i'm sure about the number i've posted as with a simple "select * from tablename" i see that value.
the tick 635924050579957219 should be 01 march 2016 04:57:37.927 GMT+1.
we have a gui that show in clear that value but wher querying the database i can only see bigint timeticks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create function dbo.converTicks(@filetime_to_convert bigint) returns datetime as begin

  Declare @TickValue bigint = @filetime_to_convert;
  Declare @Days float

  Select @Days = @TickValue * POWER(10.00000000000,-7) / 60 / 60 / 24

  return DATEADD(d, Cast(@Days As int), Cast('0001-01-01' As DATE)) 
      + Cast( (@Days - FLOOR(@Days)) As DateTime);

end;

go

select dbo.converTicks(635924050579957219) -- return 2016-03-01 04:57:37.927
-- you can use it like this:
select dbo.converTicks(t.ticksColumn) from yourTable t
```

Comment: Thank You!!! Now it works great! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the proposed solution in "Convert .NET Ticks to SQL Server DateTime" and well I can convert the ticks in a datetime format using the code:

```
Declare @filetime_to_convert bigint
Set @filetime_to_convert = 635924050579957219

Declare @TickValue bigint
Declare @Days float

Set @TickValue = 635924050579957219
Select @Days = @TickValue * POWER(10.00000000000,-7) / 60 / 60 / 24

Select DATEADD(d, Cast(@Days As int), Cast('0001-01-01' As DATE)) 
    + Cast( (@Days - FLOOR(@Days)) As DateTime)
```

now i need to insert this into a query to convert all the column 'timeticks' (as I told I'm REALLY a noob).